# How to create a docker image for shell scripts suite

Tags: linux, docker, shell

I want to create a docker image for `BBmap` suite which has a folder with multiple shell scripts (`${SHELLTOOLS}`). I have created a docker file below to create the docker image, but I also want to use helper script, `entrypoint.sh`. How do I make this docker file run with `entrypoint.sh`? Can someone please suggest me what I need to add/change to this docker file and `entrypoint.sh` so I can create a docker image and run it with the command below?

My `Docker` file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
RUN    apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        openjdk-11-jre \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV BBMAP_VERSION 38.20
ENV BBMAP_DIR /usr/local/bbmap

WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN set -eux; \
       wget -O bbmap.tar.gz https://sourceforge.net/projects/bbmap/files/BBMap_${BBMAP_VERSION}.tar.gz/download \
    && tar -zxf bbmap.tar.gz \
    && rm bbmap.tar.gz

ENV PATH ${BBMAP_DIR}:${PATH}
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
## Add ENV for Shell scripts from BBMAP
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
${SHELLTOOL} -Xmx${MEM}g in=${sortedFQ} delimiter=${DELIM} prefixmode=f column=${COLNUM} out=${sampleFQ}%_#.fq
```

My command to run this on a LSF server:

```
export SHELLTOOL="/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh"; \
export MEM=20; \
export sortedFQ="/${PR}/${FULLSM}/paire_test_sorted.fastq"; \
export column=2; \
export DELIM=":"; \
export COLNUM=2; \
export sampleFQ="/${PR}/${FULLSM}/ADNI_1380"
bsub \
    -J "${FULLSM}_bbduk_demulti" \
    -o "${BASE}/${FULLSM}_bbduk_demulti.%J" \
    -n1 -W 1440 \
    -R "rusage[mem=20192]" \
    -q research-hpc \
    -a "docker(username/bbmap:latest)" \
entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?  It seems like you need to move most of the content in the "my command" script into the entrypoint script; I might pass the command you're trying to run as the command part rather than an environment variable.

Comment: When I run the docker image, I get error for `demuxbyname.sh` not found. I am not sure what is missing on my docker file.

Comment: Where did you add the block where `SHELLTOOL` and the rest of env vars are defined?

Comment: @emi In the command : `export SHELLTOOL="/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh"; `

Comment: I mean, in the Docker environment.

Comment: Ok, if I'm not mistaken, you don't know how to add it to the Docker environment.

Comment: @New_to_R Could you solve your problem? If the answer is correct, mark as such, please

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can add all those env vars to the executed container. I'll go with plain Docker and DockerCompose solutions. It depends on your needs which one is better for you. Whichever option you take, there are a couple of variables I've not seen: `PR` and `FULLSM`. You'll probably want to add them to the top of the variables definition blocks.

#### Plain Docker

You need those variables to be defined before `entrypoint.sh` is executed. You can add them at build time or at run time. To add them at build time, you'll need to modify the Dockerfile. You can hardcode it or parameterize, even with default values:

Hardcoded

This option is good if this variables NEVER change, and NEVER will change. Just add the env vars to the Dockerfile, [as seen in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env):

```sh
# Only one ENV to add only one extra layer
ENV \
  SHELLTOOL="/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh" \
  MEM=20 \
  sortedFQ="/${PR}/${FULLSM}/paire_test_sorted.fastq" \
  column=2 \
  DELIM=":" \
  COLNUM=2 \
  sampleFQ="/${PR}/${FULLSM}/ADNI_1380"
```

Finally, rebuild your Docker container and run it. It should work.

Parameterized

This allows you to change the values with the `build` command, using the `arg` option. This is good if those variables are almost always the same, but can change from one environment to another, or may change in the future as they have already changed in the past. Furthermore, we will set them with default values, so you will have almost the same work to build it as in the first option:

```
ARG SHELLTOOL=/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh
ARG MEM=20
ARG sortedFQ=/${PR}/${FULLSM}/paire_test_sorted.fastq
ARG column=2
ARG DELIM=:
ARG COLNUM=2
ARG sampleFQ=/${PR}/${FULLSM}/ADNI_1380

ENV \
  SHELLTOOL="${SHELLTOOL}" \
  MEM=${MEM} \
  sortedFQ="${sortedFQ}" \
  column=${column} \
  DELIM="${DELIM}" \
  COLNUM=${COLNUM} \
  sampleFQ="${sampleFQ}"
```

#### docker-compose

With this tool, you can define variables to use with a container, during build time or runtime, using declarative `yaml` format. If you want to define them during build time, you'll need to use also the parameterized option explained above, allowing docker-compose to use them.

Build time

docker-compose has an option to define build arguments:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  bbmap:
    build:
      context: .
      args:                                                                     
        - SHELLTOOL=/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh
        - MEM=20
        # etc...
```

You can even include an `.env` file and use it from the `yaml`:

`.env`:

```sh
SHELLTOOL="/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh"
MEM=20
sortedFQ="/${PR}/${FULLSM}/paire_test_sorted.fastq"
column=2
DELIM=":"
COLNUM=2
sampleFQ="/${PR}/${FULLSM}/ADNI_1380"
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  bbmap:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - SHELLTOOL=${SHELLTOOL}
        - MEM=${MEM}
        # etc...
```

Run time

docker-compose has an option to define environment variables:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  bbmap:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - SHELLTOOL=/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh
      - MEM=20
      # etc...
```

As with the build `args` option, you can use an `.env` file to include them:

`.env`:

```sh
SHELLTOOL="/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh"
MEM=20
# etc...
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  bbmap:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - SHELLTOOL=${SHELLTOOL}
      - MEM=${MEM}
      # etc...
```